# Postgresql complex logic function ( plpgsql )

Tags: node.js, postgresql, plpgsql, pg

Alright i have this schemas

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=56b0781c13dfb545e9f07f82da6ae34d

- Each bill will have bunch of products saved in bill_products table
- This bill_products will be delivered and updated randomly in the near future

I need to formulate a function which would take in input of jsonb as such

```
 [ 
      {
        bill_id : 1,
        product_id : 1,
        delivered: 50
      },
      {
        bill_id : 1,
        product_id : 2,
        delivered: 400
      } 
 ]
```

Taking the above jsonb input the function should update the **bill_products** and also insert it into **inventory** table. Also if all the **bill_products** have been delivered then it should update the approved boolean to true in **bill** table

I'm new with plpgsql , could someone help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this should do it:

```
DO LANGUAGE plpgsql $$
DECLARE
    input CONSTANT jsonb := '...';
    delivery jsonb;
    updated bill_products;
BEGIN
    FOR delivery IN SELECT jsonb_array_elements(input) LOOP
        UPDATE bill_products
          SET delivered = delivered + (delivery->>'delivered')::numeric
          WHERE bill_id = (delivery->>'bill_id')::int
            AND pro_id = (delivery->>'product_id')::int
          RETURNING *
          INTO STRICT updated;
        INSERT INTO inventory(pro_id, quantity)
          VALUES (updated.pro_id, updated.delivered);
    END LOOP;
    UPDATE bill
      SET approved = NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                                 FROM bill_products
                                 WHERE bill_products.bill_id = bill.bill_id
                                   AND delivered < quantity)
      WHERE bill_id IN (SELECT DISTINCT (d->>'bill_id')::int
                        FROM jsonb_array_elements(input) d);
END;
$$;
```

([online demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=f495c2ccf51b6ad7168e912eea27d377))

Alternatively, using plain SQL instead of the loop might be even simpler:

```
WITH updates AS (
  UPDATE bill_products
  SET delivered = delivered + (delivery->>'delivered')::numeric
  FROM jsonb_array_elements(input) delivery
  WHERE bill_id = (delivery->>'bill_id')::int
    AND pro_id = (delivery->>'product_id')::int
  RETURNING pro_id, delivered
) INSERT INTO inventory(pro_id, quantity)
  SELECT * FROM updates;
```

([online demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=5a9702bac927aac6454b487f8d6b8e12))

Notice that having the delivery information duplicated in the `inventory` and `bill_products` tables is not good database design. You probably should omit the `bill_prodcts.delivered` column and rather compute the sum of the respective inventory entries every time you need it.